# When does a commit in SQLAlchemy Core get pushed to disk?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a program that is using SQLAlchemy Core to push information to an SQLite database. I am not using auto-commit transactions and am instead controlling the rate at which commits are made, as follows:

```
engine = create_engine("database")
connection = engine.connect()
transaction = connection.begin()

for index in range(0, num):
    connection.execute(EXAMPLE_INSERT)

transaction.commit()
```

Once I am done I am checking the database modify time so that I can check later to see if the database has been modified, which I am fetching using the following:

```
time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(full_path))
```

The issue that is occurring is that the database on disk seems to be getting modified after I am done with all the transactions and commits, which leads me to believe that the push to disk is occurring in some other process at some time later than the commit.

So is this correct, and if so, is there anyway to know when all the changes have been pushed to disk so I can get the correct modify time?

Comment: Why does the modification time matter for you? Databases don't normally guarantee anything about the mtime/ctime/atime of the physical file.

Comment: I'm less concerned about the modify time and more concerned about integrity. Since the db needs to be used in a program, I would like some way to verify that the db has not been altered outside of the program, otherwise the storage aspect of the db is essentially useless since I would need to compare the data source to the data storage every time the program runs. I have considered using a bytewise hash of the db, but the problem will be the same if its modified after the hash is done.

Comment: But why do you need to check that? What if someone modifies the timestamp that you've stored? How do you check that the timestamp hasn't been altered outside of the program? What are you actually trying to guard against?

Comment: I have a program that needs to store a lot of data, and it does this the first time the program is run with new source files. It takes a long time for the program to extract the data so I do not want to run it if its not necessary. I would like to, if possible, know that the next time the program runs I am dealing with an unaltered dataset otherwise I would need to run the data collection from the source material everytime the program runs, or I would have to hope it was not altered, and just fail it it was. Granted I can do the latter, I would just like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: So for an incremental build system? Why not just write a random string to a table called `versions` at the end of each transaction and use that as a comparison?

Comment: So I would store this string elsewhere, and then compare the latest string stored in the versions table to make sure it matches what I expect?

Comment: Right. It would accomplish the exact same thing that a modified timestamp or a checksum would, except more explicit because it's part of the transaction.

Comment: Are you using WAL mode? Which file system?